# What does it mean that $\left(e^{hX}\right)^*(e^{hX})=I$ if $X$ is a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $X\in M_d(\Bbb{R})$, let $h\in \Bbb{R}$. I need to find out what it means to have $$\left(e^{hX}\right)^*(e^{hX})=I$$ where $(M_{ij})^*:=\overline M_{ji}$

I know that $\left(e^{hX}\right)^*(e^{hX})=I$ is equivalent to say that $\left(e^{h\overline X_{ji}}\right)(e^{hX_{ij}})=e^{h(\overline X_{ji}+X_{ij})}=\Bbb{1}_{i=j}$ so if $i=j$ I know that we should have $\overline X_{ji}+X_{ij}=0$ or equivalently $\overline X_{ji}=-X_{ij}$. But now what does it mean if $i\neq j$? Because the exponential never can be $0$ which confuses me a bit.
Our assistant told us that we should get that $X$ satisfies $X^t=-\overline X$. I see that if $i=j$ then $X$ satisfies this assumption, but if $i\neq j$ I don't see why this assumption should hold. Can someone help me?

Comment: Be careful with combining matrix exponentials. If you do not know anything about whether or not they commute, combining them can lead to very incorrect answers. You can say that $(e^{hX})^* = e^{hX^*}$ which can be verified with the Taylor series for $e^{hX}$. If $h$ is not fixed, take a derivative of both sides with respect to $h$ then set $h = 0$. Be careful with where you place your matrices after doing the derivative. This is a pretty common trick with these products of matrix exponentials.

Comment: @CameronWilliams thanks a lot for your answer. No $h$ is arbitrarily so you would take the derivative of $(e^{hX})^* = e^{hX^*}$ on both sides and set $h=0$?

Comment: Take the derivative of your entire expression after rewriting $(e^{hX})^*$ as noted. Setting $h=0$ after doing the derivative allows you to get rid of the exponentials. Let me convert this into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $(e^{hX})^* = e^{hX^*}$. Taking a derivative of $h$ on both sides - noting that we have to do product rule - gives us

$$ e^{hX^*}X^*e^{hX} + e^{hX^*}e^{hX}X = 0. $$

Now set $h=0$ to eliminate the matrix exponentials to see something more direct about your matrix $X$.